# filter array of json objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, filter

i have the following array of json objects.

```
[{"template":{"title":"title 1"}},{"template":{"title":"title 1"}},{"template":{"title":"title1111"}},{"template":{"title":""}},{"template":{"title":""}},{"template":{"title":"this is the title"}},{"template":{"title":"title232"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"title with msg"}},{"template":{"title":"this is a title"}},{"template":{"title":"this is a title"}},{"template":{"title":"this is a title"}},{"template":{"title":"some title"}},{"template":{"title":"some title"}},{"template":{"title":"some title"}},{"template":{"title":"some title"}}]
```

i want this array to be like

```
[{'title': 'some title'}, {'title': 'some other title'}, ...]
```

so basically i don't want the template property inside the js response.
i'm getting this from the following rails code

```
@templates = Template.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id, :select=>'title', :conditions=>"title is not null")
```

`@templates.to_json` is what gives me this array of json objects

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

```
Template.include_root_in_json = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case, you could do with just collecting the attributes of your entire collection of `Template`s:

```
@templates = Template.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id, :select=>'title', :conditions=>"title is not null").collect(&:attributes)
```

(Scroll to the right to see the added `.collect(&:attributes)` at the end of the line.)